# Field is not being updated with the setData method from useForm Inertia hook

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-hooks, inertiajs

I'm setting values with the useForm hook with Inertia and react. I have a form to upload files and other input text fields. The text fields are being updated correctly but the files are not arriving in the backend in Laravel.

If I console information everything looks good but the information is simply not updated

**INPUT FILE**

```
<input
 type="file"
 name="EventFile[]"
 onChange={(e) => addFiles(e)}
 ref={inputFile}
 className="file:px-4 file:py-2 file:border-0 file:bg-yellow file:text-white file:font-bold file:drop-shadow-none file:cursor-pointer text-transparent"
 multiple
/>
```

**FUNCTION:**

```
//State
const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

// Add files
const addFiles = (event) => {

    console.log("event files", event.target.files);

    const addedFiles = [...event.target.files];

    setFiles(addedFiles);

};


// Update values for submit
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("EventFile", files);

    setData("EventFile", files);

    console.log("after set data", data);
}, [files]);
```

Event files in the console is looking good

[image]

When I submit the form my field(EventFile) is empty

[image]

I also tried adding the setData in the addFiles method but I got the same result

What could be causing that field for files not to be updated?